# Проблемы с темной темой Linux mint

Tags: linux-mint

Можно ли как-то запретить темной теме Mint-Dark Y применяться на приложения? Из-за нее невозможно работать с редакторами текста - их бэкграунд становится темным, а буквы - нечитаемыми.

Comment: В главном меню в поиске находите темы, там для пункта "Стиль окон" меняете Mint-Y-Dark на Mint-Y (или любую другую светлую). Это если у вас Cinnamon.

Comment: P.S. все остальные настройки (рамки окон, рабочий стол) оставляете от темной темы.